# convert byte[] to datatable, error, stream is not valid binary format

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to convert a byte array to a datatable.  When I try to deserialize I get an error "The input stream is not a valid binary format".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is how I am converting the raw data file to byte array;

```
            FileStream fStream = new FileStream(dirName + filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
        br.Close();
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(endpoint);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
        var serializer2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        serializer2.WriteObject(requestStream, data);
        requestStream.Close();
        var response2 = request.GetResponse();
```

This is how I am trying to convert to datatable.

```
        public string transferData(byte[] f)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataSet tempDataSet = new DataSet();
        // Deserializing into datatable    
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(f))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            dt = (DataTable)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("PostalCode:" + row["POSTAL_CODE"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("CountryCode:" + row["COUNTRY_CODE"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("ProcessNumber:" + row["PROCESS_NUMBER"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("ProcessStatus:" + row["PROCESS_STATUS"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("TimeStamp:" + row["TIMESTAMP"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
                }
            }
        }
        // Adding DataTable into DataSet    
        tempDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
```

error
{"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 54-2C-41-2C-39-31-37-2C-39-32-32-30-30-2C-46-31-2C ..."}

.  So now I am trying to deserialize using json like so...

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(f);
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(byte[]));
            stream.Position = 0;
            var x1 = (byte[])ser.ReadObject(stream);
```

new error message
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Byte[]. Encountered unexpected character 'T'.

Comment: You've left out most of the error message. For example, which line in the code you've shown causes the error?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. you serialize using *DataContractJsonSerializer*, but deserialize using *BinaryFormatter* You read file content as byte array at one end, and expect it to be DataTable at other end.

Comment: I added the error message.  maybe that is the problem.  Do you know how to use jsonserializer to convert to datatable?

Comment: ok no problem. looking into it now

Comment: I just tried to deserialize using json with sample code above... new error